# jQuery - Add Ellipses, Break Line, But Do Not Truncate

Tags: jquery, scroll, ellipsis

I would like to add ellipses to dynamic text contained within a scrollable div. However, I don't want the text to be truncated. I want the ellipses to be added, and then the text to continue on the next line. This is because the div only shows one line at a time, so the ellipses just lets the user know that there is more content and he is supposed to click the scroll arrows to continue reading.

What would be the best way to do this? ThreeDots http://tpgblog.com/threedots seems to be a very good plugin with lots of options, but I just don't know how to configure it to my need.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a height for your DIV, then use the `text-overflow: ellipsis` and prevent line-wrap CSS approach.

Here's a simple example:

```
.ellipsis {
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
-ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Of course, there's always somebody making trouble, and this time it's Firefox. You have to bind a file to the CSS.

It's easier than you might think. Just create a new text file, and call it ellipsis.xml. Then stick it anywhere on your web server where you can reference it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bindings 
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
  xmlns:xbl="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
  xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
 <binding id="ellipsis">
  <content>
    <xul:window>
     <xul:description crop="end" xbl:inherits="value=xbl:text"><children/>      
         </xul:description>
    </xul:window>
  </content>
</binding>
</bindings>
```

Then in your CSS, do this:

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -moz-binding: url('assets/xml/ellipsis.xml#ellipsis');
}
```

That's the quick run-down, and for more information check out this guy:

http://mattsnider.com/css/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/

BTW: If you think the threedots plugin is an easier choice, I say go for it.

Comment: Thanks, Shawn. That seems like it should be the solution, but I think the fact that the each bit of text is a list item of tweets is causing problems: `<div id="twitter">
  <ul id="twitter_update_list" class="scroll-pane"><li class="ellipsis"></li></ul>
</div>` It doesn't seem like CSS can handle it.